# Simple guide to payments?

Tags: paypal

I'm really struggling with trying to figure out how to make PayPal do what I want, which is frustrating because it's so simple!

What I need is pretty much just a field to enter an amount, then a checkout process that will process the payment, allowing the user to pay without creating a PayPal account if so desired. That's it, nothing fancy.

I can create a Buy Now button with the Price field left empty. This allows the user to enter an amount, but the resulting interface on PayPal's site is butt-ugly and confusing. Worse, it doesn't allow for non-PayPal payments... the only options are "Pay with my PayPal account" and "Create a PayPal account."

The Donation button does exactly what I want, but I can't use it because it looks like I may be taking in more than the yearly limit on donations, and I'm not actually a non-profit.

Is there a way to get this to work the way I want on PayPal, or do I need to write code to integrate with my site? If the latter, is there a simple, straightforward guide to how this sort of thing is done for someone with no experience at all with regard to setting up secure sites? PayPal's guides all seem to leave a lot unsaid, assuming I'm already an expert at this level of site design.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was on PayPal's end. The "account optional" setting that was supposed to be present was not. I talked to PayPal support, and they were eventually able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually (in smaller print) an option on the PayPal landing page to pay by credit card without a PayPal account. Is a dropdown with multiple price amounts a viable option?